# Running 2 or more instances of Postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-connection, backend

I have 2 versions of PostgreSQL, 9.6.1 and a modified 9.6.1. I want to run both, side-by-side so that I can compare them, so ideally they would be a replica of each other (except the part I have modified). The problem is that when I run one, the other shuts off or I am just not really sure which one is really running.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you configured different TCP port than default 5432 on one of these instances ? If no, then both servers are trying to listen on tthe same port, causing errors.

Comment: as mentioned by @krokodilko you need to run them on different ports if you are running them both on the same computer

Comment: I have created 2 clusters, registered using pg_ctl but both seem to be running 9.6 using select version();